# React Lazy Load Image Component not working in safari

Tags: reactjs

I am developing a website in React.js which has a bunch of image calls.

So it was mandatory to implement lazy loading of the images so that images present in the viewport will be only called on the initial loading of the website,

I am currently using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-lazy-load-image-component to implement lazy loading.

It is working fine in desktop browsers, android browsers but the image is not loading at all on the safari even after the scrolling.

I have also tried using 'react-lazy-load', but then also the image is not rendering in safari..

This is how i use the component in my JS file,

```
<LazyLoadImage alt="" src="someimage.png" />
```

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Are there any errors in the javascript console of safari? I would start here to debug it.

Comment: No errors are shown in the safari console, but the image is not loading at all. But working fine in chrome, chromium and firefox.

Comment: It could be a compatibility problem with CSS and safari browser ─ I don't really know. As far as I see, it's not using CSS browser prefixes. IMO this is more a question for its [bug tracker](https://github.com/Aljullu/react-lazy-load-image-component/issues) than for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed in version 1.3.0:

https://github.com/Aljullu/react-lazy-load-image-component/pull/28